# How to repeat rotation using d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to repeat a transition. I' m using [world tour](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330) with my own tsv file. The tsv file s much smaller which ends the world tour quickly.
How can I repeat the rotation so its starts at beginning?

```
       //Globe rotating
       (function transition() {
        d3.transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .each("start", function() {
          title.text(countries[i = (i + 1) % n].name);
        })
        .style("color", "lightgreen")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")

        .tween("rotate", function() {   
          var p = d3.geo.centroid(countries[i]),
              r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]]);
          return function(t) {
            projection.rotate(r(t));
            c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); //clear the canvas for redrawing
            c.fillStyle = "black", c.beginPath(), path(land), c.fill();
            c.fillStyle = "lightgreen", c.beginPath(), path(countries[i]), c.fill();
            c.strokeStyle = "green", c.lineWidth = .5, c.beginPath(), path(borders), c.stroke(); 
            c.strokeStyle = "#000", c.lineWidth = 2, c.beginPath(), path(globe), c.stroke(); 
          };
        })
      .transition()
        .each("end", transition);
  })();
}
```

Comment: This should already be looping when it gets to the end. The expression `i = (i + 1) % n` sets `i` back to zero when it reaches `n`. If it's not working, you need to check why. What is `i` set to after it passes the end of the sequence? What is `n`? Is it equal to the number of countries in the tour? It should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to reset `i` to zero when it exceeds the number of countries in your list. Something like this:

```
.each("start", function() {
  i = (i + 1) % n;

  if(i >= names.length)
    i = 0;

    title.text(countries[i].name);
  })
```

**Edit**: After looking at the World Tour example code, a simpler solution would be redefine `n` to be the length of your data (instead of the number of countries on the map):

```
      n = names.length;  // instead of countries.length
```

Then you can leave the rest of the code as is. The modulo in this expression - `i = (i + 1) % n` - will reset to zero once you reach the end of your list.